# Users are not getting mapped in OpsHub utility and loading since 3 hrs

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

I am migrating from tfs to vso, and at User mapping step it is stuck and loading since 3 hours. No users are mapped in source and destination.
Could you please help?

Comment: Is the loading bar still moving (on the top, just below the title bar)? Or has it stopped and no users were loaded?

Comment: Yes it was still moving since 4 hrs but no users are getting populated

Comment: try clearing the cache as per (http://stackoverflow.com/a/35785369/3627522) And restart the utility

Comment: Ok I will try. Can you please let me know what access rights we need on both source and migration for this utility to work?

Comment: The user through which the end-point has been authenticated will have to be in the Administrators Group in the TFS/VSTS.