# Ops Hub Migration Utility not allowing to add a remote server

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

I am trying to use the free version of Ops Hub migration utility. I am facing issues in adding the endpoints. 
I added one a Visual Studio Team Services (was Visual Studio Online) account as an endpoint, but there was some authentication issue. Post the error I am not able to add the same Team Services as an endpoint.

I have even tried uninstalling and reinstalling without any luck.
Is there some file in appdata for some other place which i need to clear so ensure that I can add the same endpoint?

Comment: What is the error message? Can you trying clearing the TFS Cache as explained in the thread (http://stackoverflow.com/a/35785369/3627522)

Comment: I got this working by removing the TFS connection string from Visual studio and adding it again.

Comment: Can you list down the exact steps that you did as an answer so someone having similar issue can refer. Thanks :)